# Android USB debug mode works in Windows not in Ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu

The Android device in question is a Micromax A87(a relatively unknown brand
in global market but I hope that should'nt matter).

In Ubuntu, I have double checked the udev rules. They all look perfect.
(I cross checked using another phone too). The USB debug mode doesn't show up
no matter what.

```
adb devices
```

shows no devices at all.

However, with the USB debugging option enabled on phone, it worked on Win7 after windows
installed a Common handset driver.

Interestingly if I now go back to Ubuntu without disconnecting the cable, it shows up there too and I see it by doing "adb devices" !!

So I guess it's not the development machine that is at fault.
The device seems to be setting a property in Windows which stays latched
till the usb connection goes off.

What could be a way to get this to work? (Besides develping on Windows :P )

> Btw the /data/property/persist.service.adb.enable is 1 too.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the USB ID for the device to ~/.android/adb_usb.ini

You should be able to get the USB ID from /var/log/messages when it is plugged in.

Restart adb with with adb kill-server; adb start-server.

Comment: I already added that. Still doesn't work.
harsha@Phobos:~$ cat .android/adb_usb.ini shows
0x1c9e

Comment: Oh, and restart it as root. I had to add my wife's Kindle HD the other night and think those are the two gotchas.

Comment: I did that too. Even the udev service. It doesn't work. Can't understand how it worked after being detected in windows and coming back to ubuntu.